# How to round decimal value up to nearest 0.05 value?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, decimal, rounding

Is there any way to round up decimal value to its nearest 0.05 value in .Net?

Ex:

7.125 -> 7.15

6.66  -> 6.7

If its now available can anyone provide me the algo?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

How about:

```
Math.Ceiling(myValue * 20) / 20
```

Comment: predator4: That seems to be what the OP wants, with the `6.66 -> 6.7` example.

Comment: Sorry. Fair enough, I've missunderstood the round up thing. To reduce confusion I've deleted my comment.

Comment: It should be noted that while this is a very good solution for the problem of rounding to arbitrary fractions, for decimal place rounding Math.Round should be used (just in case anyone comes looking at this question for a solution to more standard rounding).

Comment: Just as a warning, this can go wrong if the input is within a factor of 20 of the max value of a decimal (so, greater than about 4*10^27 for the decimal type). You can get around this by subtracting Math.floor, rounding the non-integer part, and then adding it back to the floor value. But since the original questioner's use is for a tax calculation, I doubt it matters unless it has to work in Zimbabwe...

Comment: @Steve, lol! and @predator4/user37325, your comment deletion only increased my confusion

Comment: There is a flaw in this code that will cause rounding issues, trying the value 1.41 incorrectly yields 1.5

Comment: A more straightforward way (and easier to change the round-to step) is to Math.Ceiling(myValue / 0.05) * 0.05

Answer (score 12):

Use this:

```
Math.Round(mydecimal / 0.05m, 0) * 0.05m;
```

The same logic can be used in T-SQL:

```
ROUND(@mydecimal / 0.05, 0) * 0.05
```

I prefer this approach to the [selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448458/how-to-round-decimal-value-up-to-nearest-0-05-value/1448465#1448465) simply because you can directly see the precision used.

Comment: Math.Round doesn't allow to Round UP

Comment: 0.5625 should be rounded up to .6 but it gives .55. best Math.Ceiling(myValue / 0.05) * 0.05.

Comment: Warning: this will only work if you want to round to multiples of 10. Consider the value 2671.875 and stepsize 50. I would expect the rounded value 2700. 2671.875/50 = 53.4375, which rounds to 53. But 53x50 = 2650.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this should work for any step, not just 0.05:

```
private decimal RoundUp (decimal value, decimal step)
{
    var multiplicand = Math.Ceiling (value / step);
    return step * multiplicand;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Math..::.Round Method (Decimal, Int32, MidpointRounding)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131275.aspx)

Rounds a double-precision floating-point value to the specified number of fractional digits. A parameter specifies how to round the value if it is midway between two other numbers.

```
   Math.Round(1.489,2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Comment: MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero doesn't allow to Round UP -see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I could not get proper rounding in most of the formulas

This one "rounds" to nearest

```
float roundFloat(float value, float toNearest) {
            float divVal = (1 / (toNearest == 0 ? 1 : toNearest));
            return ((float)(Math.Round(value * divVal)) / divVal);
        }
```

Result:

```
roundFloat(2, 0.125F); -> 2
roundFloat(2.11, 0.125F); -> 2.125
roundFloat(2.22, 0.125F); -> 2.25
roundFloat(2.33, 0.125F); -> 2.375
roundFloat(2.44, 0.125F); -> 2.5
roundFloat(2.549999, 0.125F); -> 2.5
roundFloat(2.659999, 0.125F); -> 2.625
roundFloat(2.769999, 0.125F); -> 2.75
roundFloat(2.879999, 0.125F); -> 2.875
roundFloat(2.989999, 0.125F); -> 3
```

Example 0.125 nearest rounding

```
 2.000 
 2.125 
 2.250 
 2.375 
 2.500 
 2.625 
 2.750 
 2.875 
 3.000
```