# Round off decimal value up to nearest 0.05 value?

Tags: java, decimal

I was reading [How to round decimal value up to nearest 0.05 value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448458/how-to-round-decimal-value-up-to-nearest-0-05-value).

It mentions the following stuff.

```
   Math.ceiling(myValue * 20) / 20
```

How does this hack work ? I mean how did we arrive at this solution?

Comment: Did you try to calculate it on a piece of paper?

Comment: Yes I did. It works. The question is , what is the reasoning that led to this hack.

Comment: Basic math, that's why I asked if you tried to calculate it on a paper. It's not a hack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no library function for rounding to 0.05, but there is one for rounding to 1.00: ceiling. That's almost (well, double isn't absolutely precise) the same as the formula that you pasted (20 * 0.05 = 1)

Did you try to substitute something for your formula and see what happens?

```
1.03 * 20 = 20.60
ceil(20.6) = 21
21/20 = 1.05
```

Answer (score 5):

1/20 is 0.05

1/100 is 0.01

If you want to round to 0.01, you multiply by 100, round and divide by 100. Similarly, to round to 0.05, you do the same, but with 20.

Answer (score 0):

it maps 0.05 to 1 (by multiplication) inside the Math.ceiling function and then maps the result back to 0.05 (by division)